# Notify std::condition_variable that waits on the std::future returned by std::async from within the async function

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable, stdasync

Given the following code my question is whether precondition of the `std::condition_variable` is guaranteed to see the `std::future` in the state after the lambda returned, i.e. `std::future_status::ready`. Or if it could happen that the `std::condition_variable` is woken up before the return value of the lambda is used to update the state of the `std::future`. In which case the worker might be stuck forever as it will not be notified again.

I guess another formulation would be whether the `inner_lock` is guaranteed to not be released before the return value of the lambda is used to update the state of the `std::future`.

In practice this seems to work fine so far. The question is more whether this guaranteed to be safe or whether there is a race condition in this code.

```
std::mutex m;
std::future<bool> task;
std::condition_variable cv;

void dispatcher() {
    std::lock_guard lock(m);

    task = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {
        // Do work...

        std::lock_guard inner_lock(m);
        cv.notify_one();
        return true;
    });
}

void worker() {
    auto task_ready = [&] {
        return task.valid() && task.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
    };

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    cv.wait(lock, task_ready);

    bool result = task.get();
    
    // Do some more work...
}
```

Comment: Looks unsafe to me. What stops the worker from responding to `notify_one()` immediately, seeing that the condition is still false, and sleeping again? Also `inner_lock` is used only in one place, that doesn't look intended.

Comment: Why would you need your own notification that the task is completed when the `future` has a notification that tells the same?

Comment: @j6t In the real code there are multiple futures involved. And I want to respond to the first once to be ready. So I can't just wait on the future(s) themselves.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `inner_lock` is only an RAII guard for the shared mutex. Also, how can the worker see the condition as false after notification? These operations are synchronized with that mutex and notification makes the condition true.

Comment: @DanielLangr from a scope perspective the mutex doesn't protect the task variable before the notification. So I wonder if the state it is correctly updated (the future knows that the function returned) before the precondition is checked after the notify.

Comment: @DanielLangr I dont think the operations are synchronized. The condition is "the future is ready". But this is not guarded by the mutex. The mutex lock is released and after that all the "inside" stuff in std::future take place and make the task valid. So the condition variable could possibly check right inside this window, see it has to wait again and waits forever

Comment: @phön You're right, my bad, I didn't realize that. Now, I agree that this seems to be wrong. I guess the problem may be resolved by using some boolean flag that would indicate that the work has been done.

Comment: @Moritz "In the real code there are multiple futures involved. And I want to respond to the first once to be ready. So I can't just wait on the future(s) themselves." i dont think there is a way to do this with vanilla/standard c++. there is still the option to spin up an asynchronus worker who just rush through all futures and checks if they finished. it is a bit wastefull tho